# jquery tooltip on dynamic element

Tags: ajax, dynamic, tooltip

I use this [tooltip](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-tooltip/) plugin to make the tooltip on element as

```
$('.showtooltip').tooltip({
            delay: 0,
            track: true,
            showURL: false,
            bodyHandler: function() {
                var tipStr = "SOME DISPLAY HTML";
                return $(tipStr);
            }
        });
```

And my ajax create element dynamically.

```
$("<img alt='' class='showtooltip' src='image.jpg' />");
```

so when this image is added to document. The tooltip doesn't display.
Then I use live() in jquery :

```
$(".showtooltip").live("mouseover", function() {
                $(this).tooltip({
                    delay: 0,
                    track: true,
                    showURL: false,
                    bodyHandler: function() {
                        var tipStr = "SOME DISPLAY HTML";
                        return $(tipStr);
                    }
                })
            });
```

But tooltip only display after the first time mouse over the image.
How can i use tooltip on dynamic element ?

Answer (score 0):

I used something like this to rebind after an ajax call. It may help.

```
$(".showtooltip").live("mouseover",function(){
   if (!$(this).hasClass("tooledUp")){
      $(this).tooltip({
                delay: 0,
                track: true,
                showURL: false,
                bodyHandler: function() {
                    var tipStr = "SOME DISPLAY HTML";
                    return $(tipStr);
                }
      });
      $(this).tooltip().show();
      $(this).addClass("tooledUp");
   }
});
```

From the forum here: http://static.flowplayer.org/tools/forum/30/37281

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="button" id="btn" value ="Click here" />

$(document).ready(function(){
$("#btn").click(function(){

    $("<input type='checkbox' title='waaaaw' />").appendTo($(this).parent()).ready(function(){
        $(this).tooltip({
                delay: 0,
                track: true,
                showURL: false,
                bodyHandler: function() {
                    var tipStr = "SOME DISPLAY HTML";
                    return $(tipStr);
                }
          }).addClass("tooledUp").show();
    });
});
});
```